# Video.js Classes to Hide Video While Loading

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I'm trying to hide a video while it's loading (e.g. the black window with just a loading spinner). The only class I've found that sort of made sense is the .vjs-has-started one but the loading screen still shows with the following CSS. I also didn't see anything in the javascript api that meets this need (sorry if I missed something).

```
.video-js {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.video-js.vjs-has-started {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

I've also tried adding .vjs-playing into the mix both in place of an in conjunction with .vjs-has-started. Any thoughts on getting this to work or a answer about why it won't currently would help. If I need to I can work on adding this to video.js if it's not already there but I first wanted to get your definitive answer on the current state of video.js for this functionality.

Comment: Started a fix to this at https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/1351. Awaiting feedback from the owner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the vjs-waiting class to be able to accomplish this now vjs-waiting can be used in css to show and hide the content see the pull-request for more details.

Example:

```
.vjs-waiting {
  visibility: hidden;
  background: transparent;
}
.vjs-loading-spinner {
  display: none !important;
}
```

*Reference - https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/1351*

Answer (score 0):

You could use the vjs-waiting

```
.vjs-waiting {visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: I did the work to add vjs-waiting after this question went unanswered. It was merged August 1st. So I'm not accepting your answer as you just usurped my work.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have been struggling with this too, Docs are not intuitive at all!

Im implementing Video JS in React Hooks, so I solved with **loadingSpinner** set to false;

```
useEffect(() => {
    let player = videojs('my-player',{
        autoplay: 'muted',
        sources: [
            {
                src: videoUrl, // m3u8 format
                type: "application/x-mpegURL"
            }
        ],
        controlBar: false,
        loadingSpinner: false
      });
    player.play()
    return () => {
        player.dispose()
    }
}, [])
```

Hope it helps! =)